# Convert One String into a list of Int

Tags: python, string, list, int

I would like to know how to convert a string like `"1 -2 -8 4 5"` into something like `[1, -2, -8, 4, 5]`

Comment: ```I would like to know how to ...``` - Work your way through [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and you will start getting ideas how to solve the problem.  Look through [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) to get some more ideas.  Try some of your ideas out.

Answer (score 3):

I'd split the string by the `" "` character, and convert each element to an `int`:

```
myList = [int(x) for x in myString.split(" ")]
```

or simply

```
myList = [int(x) for x in myString.split()]
```

by default split uses the white space `' '` as argument

Answer (score 0):

```
array=list(map(int,string.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(int , string.split(' ')))
```

Split with a space.